# Copy and pasting blocks of text anywhere

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have two blocks of text and I want to merge them. However, the problem is that the blocks are not synchronous and I want to place one in front of the other completely. For example, suppose we have the following block of text:

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
```

and the following block:

```
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
```

And I want to merge them thus:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
```

I can't copy line by line because there are many lines in both files and they could be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all 'bbbb..' text using `Ctrl-V` (visual block selection mode), yank; then go to the last char of the first `aaaa...` string, hit `Ctrl-V` again; go down to the last `aaaa ...` string, while staying in the same column (so cursor is still on the last `a` character). You are still in block selection mode. Hit 'p' to paste.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right, as it deletes the last `a` in each row for me.

Comment: Hah, you're right :) But the idea is still the same - just do it in the other direction, and 'prepend' to the line using `P`.

Comment: For me it was a bunch of assignment statements, so I ended up adding a bunch of spaces after the first line to not clobber the longer variable names. But it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Visual-block select (C-V) the text you want to prepend, then either yank/delete the text.  Go to the first line and character of the text you want to prepend to, then press P (upper case P).